# Running code when mongoengine loads a document

Tags: pymongo, mongoengine

We are trying to run code that modifies a document when it loads as part of schema maintenance. We have a document such as

```
from mongoengine import Document
from mongoengine.fields import IntField, StringField

class User(Document):
    version = IntField(default=0)
    name = StringField()
```

Instances of User are created with version=1 and saved.

Later on, we modify this class as follows:

```
class User(Document):
    version = IntField(default=0)
    name = StringField(max_length=20)
```

Some of the version 1 documents now need to be truncated:

```
    def upgrade_1_to_2(self):
        self.name = self.name[:20]
```

We want to automatically run that function whenever a User is retrieved from the database, and only if version == 1. (Future upgrades would be upgrade_2_to_3(), and so on.)

Where in this API can I put code that runs when a document is retrieved?

Comment: Could you do do a batch process when you upgrade your version? and run it one time against all the Users in the systm? Like a migration?

Comment: That is our fallback approach, but it has some issues, mainly there's a serious blocking vs. consistency problem. Either your application has to wait for it to finish, or your application is using out-of-date objects while it works. We want to do it this way to avoid those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a good candidate for the `post_init` signal and you can do a check there.

See: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/signals.html